# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level even though my indentation is correct

Tags: python

**What I am trying to do**

I have a simple function for `string` input validation.

Code:

```
def get_string_input(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            value = str(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            time.sleep(0.3)
            print("Incorrect command. Please try again")
            continue

        if type(value) != str:
            time.sleep(0.3)
            print("Incorrect command. Please try again")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return value

# Test

get_string_input('What is your name? ')
```

**Problem:**

When I run the program, I recieve the following error:

[image]

I can see that my indentation is correct, so why is it giving me an error?

Comment: Is this the actual code? I ran it on my system and it worked fine.

Comment: interesting. i just copied it from my question here back into my program and it works fine for some reason...

Comment: Perhaps there was some problem with the code but when you copied it over you accidently fixed it. Anyways use the code you posted here.

Comment: You had mixed tabs and spaces. Copying the question back in solved it for you... (probably used only spaces)

Comment: oh ok. i understand now. thanks for that. and yes the question you linked/your answer have answered my question :D

Comment: In future, if the interpreter says you have an indentation error (or any other syntax error) bear in mind *that the interpreter is always right* in this regard, whatever you may think, because the interpreter is an operational definition of correctness.

Comment: ok :D thanks for that